# Get img src from table

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kkm2.jpg)

Need help with extracting img src from a table. I am using Puppeteer in Node.js for scraping. I can retrieve colorCode and ColorDescription but having hard time getting the img src.

```
puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false
    }).then(async function (browser) {
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://www.automotivetouchup.com/touch-up-paint/alfa-romeo/2024/all-models/')

  const dataReturn = []
  class dataItem {
    constructor(chip, colorCode, colorDescription) {
      this.chip = chip
      this.colorCode = colorCode
      this.colorDescription = colorDescription
      //this.date = date
      //this.source = source
    }
  }
  const tableSelector = 'div > table > tbody'
  const dataReturnLength = await page.$$eval(`${tableSelector} > tr`, el => el.length)

  // iterate over tr:nth-child(${i}) on all rows
  for (let i = 2; i < dataReturnLength + 1; i++) {
    const chip = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > img`))
    const colorCode = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(2)`))
    const colorDescription = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(3)`))

    const actualdataItem = new dataItem(chip, colorCode, colorDescription)
    dataReturn.push(actualdataItem)
  }
  console.log(dataReturn)

  await browser.close()
})
```

Comment: I already figured out how to fix. Thanks for the view.

Comment: Consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your solution to help others with the same problem as you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelector("img").src` to grab the image from that first table cell.

That said, there are a number of inefficiencies in your code. One example is running two evaluates when one is plenty:

```js
await page.evaluate(
  el => el.innerText,
  await page.$(`${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > img`)
)
```

could be

```js
await page.$eval(
  `${tableSelector} > tr:nth-child(${i}) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > img`,
  el => el.innerText
);
```

...and you can simplify the selector to avoid `nth-child` as I'll illustrate below.

Here's a simpler version that also blocks all requests and disables JS to improve speed:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.11.1

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", request => {
    request.url() === url ? request.continue() : request.abort();
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const results = await page.$$eval("tr", rows => {
    const headers = [...rows[0].querySelectorAll("th")].map(
      e => e.textContent
    );
    return rows
      .slice(1)
      .map(row =>
        Object.fromEntries(
          [...row.querySelectorAll("td")].map((cell, i) => [
            headers[i],
              cell.textContent.trim() ||
              cell.querySelector("img")?.src
          ])
        )
      );
  });
  console.log(results);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Once you get to the point that you're blocking everything except the static HTML, you can usually skip Puppeteer entirely in favor of a simple HTTP request and a static, plain-text HTML parser like Cheerio:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url) // built into Node 18+
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const headers = [...$("th")].map(e => $(e).text());
    const results = [...$("tr")]
      .slice(1)
      .map(e =>
        Object.fromEntries(
          [...$(e).find("td")].map((e, i) => [
            headers[i],
            $(e).text().trim() || $(e).find("img").attr("src"),
          ])
        )
      );
    console.log(results);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Rough benchmarks:

- OP Puppeteer (with `headless: true` added): 7.1s
- My Puppeteer rewrite: 4.9s
- Fetch/Cheerio: 2.2s